# Parsing a website with VBA following various links

Tags: vba, loops, parsing, web

I am trying to download data from a website that is within a table.

The actual downloading works fine as long as I know the direct link to the page. One page though has data on various sub-pages and I would first load the links, and then follow each of the links on page 1.

Trouble is, that once I load a sub-page, the object variable holding the initial links is lost. How can I preserve the object variable?

My code so far looks like this:

```
     ...
     more code here
     ...

     ieApp.Navigate "http://www.website.com/blabla"
     Do While ieApp.Busy: Sleep 500: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

     Set rcl = ieApp.Document.getElementsbyClassName("col-md-3")

     For Each ahref In rcl(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
        ieApp.Navigate ahref.href
        Do While ieApp.Busy: Sleep 500: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

        ' Now get the data

        Call subSaveRecords 

     Next

     ...
     continue more
     ...
```

Basically after I initiate the ieApp.navigate within the For Each the rcl-Object/ahref object is lost as the ieApp has a new page. How can I "preserve" the object values while still moving onwards to new pages?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply create a new object for open the sublinks and pass the object to the subroutine for get the data?

```
set ie2 = CreateObject(internetexplorer.application)
ieApp.Navigate "http://www.website.com/blabla"
Do While ieApp.Busy: Sleep 500: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set rcl = ieApp.Document.getElementsbyClassName("col-md-3")

For Each ahref In rcl(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
   ie2.Navigate ahref.href
   Do While ie2.Busy: Sleep 500: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until ie2.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

   'Now get the data

   Call subSaveRecords ie2
Next
```

Or you can add the link to a collection or an array before changing page.

```
ieApp.Navigate "http://www.website.com/blabla"
Do While ieApp.Busy: Sleep 500: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set rcl = ieApp.Document.getElementsbyClassName("col-md-3")
For Each ahref in rcl(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
   linkCollection.add ahref.href
Next ahref

For Each ahref In linkCollection
   ieApp.Navigate ahref
   Do While ieApp.Busy: Sleep 500: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

   'Now get the data

   Call subSaveRecords
Next
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I went for the second option, as the site is one where I have to login and I feel like opening up two browsers is less elegant. Great help!!